# How to change the entire background of vim

Tags: vim

I am using a colorscheme that defaults to using a grey-ish background on unoccupied lines, for example:

[image]
[image]

What is the colorscheme entry that determines what the background will be in unused lines, and how would I change that to just being white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background of unused lines is controlled/set by `Highlight command`

```
:help :hi


12. Highlight command                   *:highlight* *:hi* *E28* *E411* *E415*

There are three types of highlight groups:
- The ones used for specific languages.  For these the name starts with the
  name of the language.  Many of these don't have any attributes, but are
  linked to a group of the second type.
- The ones used for all syntax languages.
- The ones used for the 'highlight' option.
```

You can see all the groups currently active with this command:

```
:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim


Highlighting groups for various occasions
-----------------------------------------
SpecialKey      SpecialKey
NonText         NonText
Directory       Directory

~
```

You can set the color of unused lines as follow:

```
:hi NonText ctermbg=BlACK
```

Example:

[image: Exampel]:

Set to `:hi NonText ctermbg=NONE` for no color